# Dynamically add form element

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Did my best to look trough searches and suggested titles but couldn't find an answer. I have a jQuery mobile page that gets generated via PHP.

So on this page I got a select dropdown (city) and upon selecting the city I want a second select dropdown do appear below this one, one containing suburbs. I got a php page that spits back the html needed for injection.

```
$('#city').change(function() {
  alert($('#city').val());
  if($('#city').val() != "") {
    $.get( 'get_burb.php', { city: $('#city').val() }, function(data) {
      alert(data);
    } );
  }
});
```

everything checks out, the data is just what I need. so where do I put this now? sorry for the newbness, I can't wrap my head around this jQuery stuff.

edit:

after didn't do anything to it, it was inside a fieldcontain, took me a while to figure that out. also, there was the issue that the newly injected field didn't have the styling of standard controls. also, if the user changes the city, we need to reload the html and remove it alltogether if city got no 'burbs.

after countless tries and fails, I got the job done by putting an empty div (#here) inside the fieldcontain and then playing around with it like so:

```
$('#city').change(function() {
    //alert($('#city').val());
    if($('#city').val() != "") {
        $.get( 'get_burb.php', { city: $('#city').val() }, function(data) {
            $('#burb').remove();
            $('#here').empty();
            $("#here").append( data ).trigger('create');
        } );
    } else {
        $('#burb').remove();
        $('#here').empty();
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you read through the jQuery function list?

Comment: did you manage to get 40k posts by posting useless stuff like this?

Comment: Did you manage to find yourself in a situation where you couldn't solve your problems, by not bothering to read documentation? Getting snarky isn't going to help! You're better off assuming that 40k means I know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#city').after(data)
```

Should do the trick. This will insert the HTML in `data` after the select box with the id `city`.

Answer (score 0):

check out [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$('#city').after(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

THe part you are probably having issue with "getting your head around" is that JQMobile uses html to generate other HTML at runtime. so a list for example may be generated one way before the page is rendered, and looks different (in terms of html tags) after the rendering has taken place. That confused me for a while.

I recommend getting firebug to have a look at what is happening in your page to try and understand what things start off as and what they end up as. Some JQM functions will call the page() function which will render the controls correctly, ie transform them to what you see on the page, and others wont. Knowing that, should help you to identify what your actual issue is.

With combo boxes you will find that your data probably is being changed and will probably require a function call of some sort to update it.